# Mono MVC3 ActionLink datetime RouteValue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mono

I'm running ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor) web application with Apache + Mono 2.10.5

I have a problem with the `Html.ActionLink` helper when I'm using date as RouteValue parameter.  For example:

@Html.ActionLink("link name", "ActionName", new { datum = DateTime.Now })

When I'm running app with Cassini or IIS, the date part is serialized like US datetime (`MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS`), and everything is as expected.

But Mono is taking my locale culture into account ('hr-HR', serialization DD.MM.YYYY HH.MI.SS),
and I get the wrong date in the controller (I suppose controller isn't taking current culture into account).

Is it a bug, or I'm missing something?

Comment: +1 for using Mono with ASP.NET MVC3; care to tell how you got started?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `yyyy-MM-dd` which is the standard format for dates used in GET requests (as query string parameters):

```
@Html.ActionLink("link name", "ActionName", new { datum = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

Comment: I'm already doing something like that (I've created extension method for DateTime), but I was wondering is that a Mono bug, or it's expected behavior (and IIS is using some magic to deal with it).

Comment: @edgecrusher, always use the `yyyy-MM-dd` format when sending dates as query string parameters.